# Moving home directory to my HDD and fixing partitions after migrating from Windows

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, disk, home-directory

I have a Dell laptop with an SSD (Formerly C: partition in Windows) where I want to keep my OS and package files, while moving home directory to HDD (Formerly D:). Now I am not too familiar with partitions, partition types, disk content types; so I don't want to mess up anything - I just need help with these things:

1. Move my ~ home directory to my HDD.
2. Choose correct drive configuration (Right now I think this partition type is of Windows type Basic Data and NTFS contents) (see image below).
3. Merge free space (70GB) with Partition 2 (see image below).
4. If possible, can my HDD be seamlessly integrated into the file system without it being "mounted", I just want it to be a normal directory. Right now, if I access this part of my file system, a disk icon appears on the dock with an option to unmount it when right clicked.

Hard disk partition information:

[image: Hard disk partition information]

EDIT:
Including content of `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=6787a347-fa8d-4880-a371-700361c74ec4 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=067C-1A89  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Output of `lsblk`:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0   9,1M  1 loop /snap/canonical-livepatch/95
loop1    7:1    0  97,1M  1 loop /snap/core/9993
loop2    7:2    0  55,3M  1 loop /snap/core18/1885
loop3    7:3    0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1880
loop4    7:4    0  29,9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/8542
loop5    7:5    0 146,5M  1 loop /snap/code/45
loop6    7:6    0 255,6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
loop7    7:7    0 217,9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60
loop8    7:8    0  62,1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop9    7:9    0  49,8M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/467
loop10   7:10   0  30,3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/9279
loop11   7:11   0 146,5M  1 loop /snap/code/46
sda      8:0    0 223,6G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0 223,1G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 465,8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   128M  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   0 400,4G  0 part /media/julius/Duomenys
```

Comment: Do you have any reason not to wipe the HDD? You should change the filesystem to a Linux filesystem such as ext4 if you want place your home directory there. What is in the small partition on the HDD? Potentially you can wipe the whole disk, place a single large partition there and format it as ext4 with Gparted. There are plenty of guides around about how to move home. They will include adding an entry to /etc/fstab so it all mounts at boot. Answer my questions and add the contents of /etc/fstab and the output of lsblk to your question for further help.

Comment: @PonJar I have some files on my HDD, but I can backup them and wipe disk afterwards. Partition 1 type is "Microsoft reserved", a small chunk of unknown contents. I guess this one can be merged into partition 2 then as well. Will edit my question to include requested info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't be too hard since you don't have much on your HDD. I suggest the following steps:

1. Backup any data on the HDD that you want to keep
2. Use Gparted to delete the existing partitions on the HDD, unmounting them first if necessary.
3. Use Gparted to create one large partition on the HDD and format it with a filesystem. ext4 is a good choice
4. Follow this guide to move your home: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

If you have any issues ask further questions